# Display a .msg file using WPF in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, msg

I am currently designing and implementing an application whereby a user can preview and classify emails (amongst other features). I wish to create a 'preview' of the email message which is in a .msg file format and display it to the user.

I am using C# so this is really a two part question. How do I get the .msg file into C# and secondly how do I display a preview within WPF? I am not asking for a full implementation (although it would be nice :p) but any comments or tips are extremely welcome.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the first question:

[Reading an Outlook MSG File in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/reading_an_outlook_msg.aspx)

Comment: I had a brief look over this, does this keep pictures included within the email. I want to be able to view the email pretty much as you would see it in Outlook. Sorry if I didnt make it clear or I am misunderstanding what I am reading in your link

Comment: I'm the author of the linked article the Images etc are all available in the `Attachments` of the message so you have access to enough info to achieve what you want though it isn't straight out of the box. When displaying I currently get the body as html lookup the image tags with references to their cid's then inline the images using data uri's